# How to check that the current process is running as Windows Service using WinAPI functions?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I have a program that can be run as a simple console application or can be registered as Windows Service. I want to detect in `main()` function the current running context:

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL IsWindowsService()
{
    ???
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (IsWindowsService())
    {
        // Running as Windows Service...
        RunService();
        return;
    }

    // Running as console application...    
    return 0;
}
```

The main use-case is to have a single exe file that can be installed and run as a Windows Service with '--install' and '--start' arguments or executed without any parameters in console mode (e.g. from VS debugger).

Can you help me with a possible implementation of `IsWindowsService()` function?

Comment: when you register your application as service - set some commandline, known to you, and then check command line - based on this you can understand are you exec via service key with this command line or no. best of all use symbols like `<`, `>`, `|` which can not be in command line if your application exe via some filesystem shell

Comment: Now that you've added the mention of `--start` parameter, you don't need an `IsWindowsService()` function at all, you just need to inspect the parameters.

Comment: I need because `--start` parameter check with `StartService()` is used only outside the `IsWindowsService()` scope!

Comment: Your parameters are right there -- `argc` and `argv` -- so just move your parameter processing before you need to make the decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
    { 
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] =
    {
        { SERVICE_NAME,(LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain },
    { NULL,NULL }
    };
    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable))
        //service
    else app; // last error ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT
}


VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{...}
```

Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicectrldispatchera

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I found an elegant solution for the problem which does not require providing special command line argument to handle (solution provided by @RbMn):

```
BOOL IsWindowsService()
{
    DWORD sessionId = 0;
    ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &sessionId);
    return !sessionId;
}
```

This solution works because [all Windows Services run in Session 0 along with applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85)).

Comment: This does not tell you that your application is a service.  It could be spawned from a service.  Can you clarify your question to explain whether "spawned from a service" should or should not count?

Comment: My use case is to have a single exe file that can be installed and run as a Windows Service with '--install' and '--start' arguments or executed without any parameters in console mode (e.g. from VS debugger).

Comment: I understand that.  Both your method and Michael's will give the correct answer in those two cases.  They will give a different answer in the case your exe file is spawned from another service.. What answer do you want in that case?

Comment: Also consider that Michael's method is "perfect" in the sense that it adds no new code at all to the service path.  The service path *must* call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`.  So you get its return value for free.

Answer (score -3):

You can use ***system()*** function. It will execute any command that can run on command prompt. Use it like this:

```
system("tasklist > tasks.txt");
```

This will store all running tasks to ***tasks.txt***. Then you can check is your program running or not by searching for it in the file.

for more information about ***tasklist***, run command prompt, execute this:

```
tasklist /?
```